# Extracting hour value from datetime column using DATEPART function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to extract the numerical hour value from a column that contains time formatted as DateTime.  For example, here are a couple of records from that column:

```
Time Aired
4:20:00 PM
12:51:00 PM
3:17:00 PM
3:24:00 PM
```

From this column I'm trying to extract 4, 12, 3, 3, etc.  The DATEPART function appears to be a good option for this.  However, when I try to use that function as shown below I'm prompted to enter a parameter for Hour.  This leads me to believe I'm implementing DATEPART incorrectly.  Can someone spot what the problem may be? Could the problem be that my datetime formatted column contains time values only?

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, [Time Aired]) AS Foo
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Time Aired] <> null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php) shows that the interval part (`hours`) should be enclosed in quotes and it should be `h`, not `hours`; therefore, try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART("h", [Time Aired]) AS Foo
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Time Aired] is not null;
```

My other question would be, aren't you supposed to write `WHERE [Time Aired] is not null` ?

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know how I overlooked the quotes in the documentation.  Regarding the WHERE statement, both versions work.  I don't know if one is better.

Comment: Yes I get the same query results if I use <> null

Comment: It's been a few years, so hopefully you're using "is not null" instead of "<> null" by now. Reference: [How to Get NULLs Horribly Wrong](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HOUR function instead of DATEPART.It gives hour numbers irrespective of AM/PM

```
SELECT HOUR([Time Aired]) AS Foo
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Time Aired] <> null;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about HOUR.  I'm not sure whether to select your answer or @Icarus.  Both get the job done.  I'll leave the question open for a bit to see of the votes indicate whether one approach is better.

Comment: DatePart("h", "01/05/2012 9:54 PM") returns 21 and not 9.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can ***extract only the number of hours*** from an MS Access `Date` value in a query expression a few ways.

**Here are some of the methods:**

```
DatePart("h", [yourFieldName])  'returns a variant (Integer)

Format([yourFieldName],"h")     'returns a variant (String)

Hour([yourFieldName])           'returns a variant (Integer)
```

In Access, I prefer the last method because it's short and clear.

---

Based on the question, I suspect you were looking at the documentation for the [SQL Server `DATEPART` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) which has some subtle differences.

Don't make the mistake of thinking that SQL is all the same.  There *are* similarities but **the syntax is not always interchangeable**, especially when talking about MS Access. When searching for answers about Access, I always include **`mc access`** as part of my Google search query, *and even still*, when you find a potential answer, confirm that the page you're looking at was actually written for Access.

---

## Your NULL problem

There's something you didn't *ask* for help for, but that you *need* help with! :) Indeed this is an old post, so you must have either figured out your mistake, *or* you're still stuck on it, *or* the company has been putting out incorrect reports for the last 6 years.

- `[myFieldName] Is Not Null` is **not** the same as `[myFieldName] <> Null`.

The short explanation is that **Null is not a value**.  Null can things around it.  It's **not** a zero, it's **not** a `''` empty string, and it's not a ZLS (zero-length-string).

The way you were using the `<> NULL` criteria it's likely your query was returning **no records** because of the incorrect syntax.

---

## Examples:

For example: what result do you think this simple equation will produce?

```
(Null+2)*3
```

...if you said `6`, *you're **wrong***!

The result is:  `NULL`.  Basically, anything that touches `NULL` becomes `NULL`.

One more example.  **Run this in VBA**:

```
 If Null = Null Then MsgBox "Null equals Null." Else MsgBox "Null does NOT equal Null."
```

...you *might **not*** get the answer you'd expect!

For accuracy, all operators must be used the way they were intended, including the use of `Is` and `Is Not` operators with [the `NULL` Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/null-statement).

---

## More Information:

- Office Support : [**`DatePart` Function** (Access Query *or* VBA)](https://support.office.com/article/datepart-function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa)
- Office Support : [**`Format` Function** (Access Query *or* VBA)](https://support.office.com/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530)
- Office Support : [**`Hour` Function** (Access Query *or* VBA)](https://support.office.com/article/hour-function-97b6b99c-c21d-41cd-b49a-98df6955778f)
- Allen Browne : [**Common Errors with Null**](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html)
- Red-Gate : [**How to get `NULL`s Terribly Wrong in SQL Server**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/)
- TechRepublic : [**10 tricks for handling `Null` values in Microsoft Access**](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/)
- Wikipedia : [***`Null`*** (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null)
- MSDN: [**`Is`** Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/is-operator)

---

> ### Preparing for Unexpected Data:
>
> This is actually only *barely* related, but made me LMAO because I never woudl have thought to prepare for this, and I figured I ought to share:
>
> [image: img]
>
> ...which, in return, reminds me of that annoying little kid, *[Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).*